# How to generate multiple commands with multiple args in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Currently here's how I generate command with multiple args in k8s, which works well:

```
args = ["-f1", "f1", "-f2", "f2", ...]
cmd = ["cmd1"]
V1Container(command=cmd, args=args)
```

Now I need to expand to two commands, so I need sth like:
`cmd0 && cmd1 -f1 f1 -f f2...`

So how can I enable this? Obviously if I just do `cmd=["cmd0 && cmd1"]` and keep args the same, and it won't work. And I've had many tries but also no luck. Thanks